# showing subfolders in google drive using python api

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to list all folders(and subfolders) in google drive.

My root folder has six subfolders in it. but my code is only showing files.

```
def credentials_from_file():
    """Load credentials from a service account file
    Args:
        None
    Returns: service account credential object

    https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount
    """

    # https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#drivev3
    SCOPES = [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
    ]
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = './auth_creds.json'

    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)


    return credentials

credentials = credentials_from_file()
service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)


results = service.files().list(pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
items = results.get('files', [])

if not items:
    print('No files found.')
else:
    print('Files:')
    for item in items:
        print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))
```

How do I get it to tell me the subfolders as well?
Thanks!

UPDATE #1.  This is teh OAuth version.  It allows the browser to create a token, and then should run, but after the token is created, it freezes on execution:

```
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
from getfilelistpy import getfilelist

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'

store = file.Storage('token.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('rrc_crds.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)

resource = {
    "oauth2": creds.authorize(Http()),
    "fields": "files(name,id)",
}
res = getfilelist.GetFileList(resource)  # or r = getfilelist.GetFolderTree(resource)
print(res)
```

Comment: Is this library useful for your situation? https://github.com/tanaikech/getfilelistpy

Comment: Thanks.  still not showing subfolders.  Appreciate your insight tho.  is a good roster.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your situation, how about this? In your script, you are using Service Account. If you want to retrieve the folder list on your own Google Drive, please use OAuth2, because the Drive of Service Account is different from your Drive that you login using your Google account. If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Comment: No.  you got it right.  but OAuth2 requires me to go through a browser, yes?  I tried PyDrive, and everytime I tried it, it required a browser interface.  I need headless.  Am I missing something?

Comment: When you use OAuth2, only at first, you are required to authorize the scopes by own browser. By this, a refresh token can be retrieved. After 2nd time, you are not required to use the browser. The access token can be retrieved by the refresh token. Or, if you want to use Service Account, for example, how about putting the 6 folder to a folder and sharing the folder with the Service Account? By this, you can retrieve the folder list using the Service Account. Are these useful for your situation?

Comment: I'm trying Oauth2 however it seems to be sticking.  I'll put my code in the window.

Comment: I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: sorry Tanaike, it was not resolved.  I started this, however when I tried to run the code, it freezes.  I'm still trying to figure it out.

Comment: I apologize I misunderstood your current situation. In your added script, I thought that it might take a long time because all files in the Drive are retrieved. So as a test run, please set the specific folder ID of a folder which has a small number of files and folders. ``resource`` becomes like ``resource = {"oauth2": creds.authorize(Http()), "id": "### folder ID ###", "fields": "files(name,id)"}``. By this, the process time will be shorter.

Comment: That did it.  I got the folders I'm looking for.  Thanks so much!

Comment: can you please wrap all of this up so I can push you points for answering?  THanks

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. And also thank you for your proposal. I posted an answer. Could you please confirm it? Also I think that this might be also useful other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to propose the following modification.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, you are using Service Account. From your comment, I could understand that you want to retrieve files in you own Google Drive. So I propose to use OAuth2 for this situation, because the Drive of Service Account is different from your Drive that you login using your Google account.
- About the script, in order to retrieve all files and folders under a specific folder, I have published a library for this. So here, I would like to propose it.

  - The library is https://github.com/tanaikech/getfilelistpy. This library uses the method of list in Drive API v3.
  - You can install by `$ pip install getfilelistpy`.

#### Sample script:

A sample script using OAuth2 is as follows. In this sample script, the process of OAuth2 uses [the quickstart of Google](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python). Please check this before you run the script.

```
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
from getfilelistpy import getfilelist

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'

store = file.Storage('token.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)

resource = {
    "oauth2": creds.authorize(Http()),
    "id": "### Folder ID ###",
    "fields": "files(name,id)",
}
res = getfilelist.GetFileList(resource)  # or r = getfilelist.GetFolderTree(resource)
print(res)
```

- If you don't use `"id": "### Folder ID ###"`, all files in own Google Drive are retrieved. So when a lot of files in your drive, it will take a long time. So at first, please use the specific folder ID of a folder which has a small number of files and folders as a test run.

#### References:

- [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
- [getfilelistpy of python library](https://github.com/tanaikech/getfilelistpy)