# Google drive API returns 400 Bad request on using PageToken

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client, http-error

I am trying to access the next page files in google drive API v3. But this particular snippet fails.

I checked out https://stackoverflow.com/a/38479234/11705040 but my query `query_string="'{0}' in parents".format(item["id"])` seems fine by this post.

```
temp = (
       self.service.files().list(
           q=query_string,
           pageToken=nextPageToken,
           pageSize=5,
           fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name, mimeType, size, parents, modifiedTime)",
       ).execute()
   )
```

Error is this:

```
File "D:\Mac\Sites\project-reconnaissance\cronjob\env\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 134, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Mac\Sites\project-reconnaissance\cronjob\env\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 907, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=%271a49i6ivoZ_ErAin7KvvG9VBZOyeeImqc%27+in+parents&pageToken=~%21%21~AI9FV7TwnBwo_MYMR8Rap94OgbFCPDWcy3n6C7prOb_V7MjhT6tjVHHP58QBSyROFNI4HtgmMW6o1AznGcmN1yF_wKr5SSlSgiDocew78RYuyZXDdGO6WOnhrkNeuYW3RyD1nSSWKXNro-skWfZgMuKpQ9P1QfnAxQbdiXAVQ8lO6J2b_xzwpMhAjLWV1kOMCsTqVP9wI61SYJGa1qRJwhUzwL6OEaqffuhXaH3Aa6aXUWg6aIwzAYqGuwTDu1S9BIAqSE3qXDKpRebmvC-fXz0iiDlqlPsuJA-MWuzSNIk0_XlgRpRavrGN9c5miN32i9JML6VQNKs9c_mdb3Ggwzm8KUlPO8eeYg8rdM9gwg6asch22HjLNeKc5kqIRjG9OjVA0RVovpvE&pageSize=5&fields=nextPageToken%2C+files%28id%2C+name%2C+mimeType%2C+size%2C+parents%2C+modifiedTime%29&alt=json returned "Invalid Value">
```

**EDIT**
Adding a minimum reproducible example:
This issue is faced when I'm trying to run the query in a sub folder

```
import os
import pickle
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

ID = "1a49i6ivoZ_ErAin7KvvG9VBZOyeeImqc"

SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly"]


def get_gdrive_service():
    """Gets the service object of google drive"""
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists("token.pickle"):
        with open("token.pickle", "rb") as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                "credentials.json", SCOPES
            )
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open("token.pickle", "wb") as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)
    # return Google Drive API service
    return build("drive", "v3", credentials=creds)


print("connecting to google drive...")
service = get_gdrive_service()
print("connected to google drive!")


def list_files(query_string, nextPageToken=None):
    """List the google drive files as returned by Google Drive API."""

    # Get the first set of results
    # BUG here when coming from line 68
    items = (
        service.files().list(
            q=query_string,
            pageToken=nextPageToken,
            pageSize=5,
            fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name, mimeType, size, parents, modifiedTime)",
        )
        .execute()
    )

    if items['files'] != []:
        print("get first set of results", items)

    nextPageToken = items.get("nextPageToken")
    items = items.get("files", [])

    # Do this for all internal folders as well
    for item in items:
        print("Doing item:", item["name"])
        # This works fine
        list_files(
            query_string="'{0}' in parents".format(item["id"])
        )

    # If there is a nextPage Token, go further to get next set of items
    if nextPageToken:
        print("Fetching next set of results")
        q = "'{0}' in parents".format(ID)
        # SOME BUG in line 50 when going from here, fails with HTTP 400
        list_files(q, nextPageToken=nextPageToken)


list_files("'{0}' in parents".format(ID))
```

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your issue, can you provide your whole script for replicating your issue? In that case, please remove your personal information if those are included.

Comment: Edits, also gave a test folder_id incase replicating the structure

Comment: So essentially you are trying to list folders within a folder or all the files within a folder? @NautatavaNavlakha

Comment: Files actually, if it is a folder, it goes in a recursive way to list the files in a folder

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, when I tested your script, I cannot replicate your issue of `Invalid Value`. So for example, in order to retrieve the file list with the folder structure, is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/55009747

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting the same thing. The issue was the query can't change at all. So add the next page token but otherwise you need to send everything else exactly the way it was when it generated the token.

Comment: Yes, went through the code 10 times and realized this, thanks for the answer though!